# Anylogic: fixed production cost with system dynamics

Tags: anylogic, systemdynamics

I would like to formalise this problem with system dynamics: I have a stock of raw materials and one of finished goods, among them I have a production flow that has a certain value (e.g 1000 units per day). My goal is to calculate the manufacturing cost, so I create a flow that feeds a stock "manufacturing cost" and within the flow I have the product of:

Manufacturing_cost_flow = Unit_variable_cost * production_rate   [$/unit] * [unit/time]

Now, I would like to enter the fixed costs. In particular, if I have a shortage of raw materials (so RM = 0 --> production_rate = 0) the manufacturing_cost_flow will be 0 but, in fact, I have to sustain a fixed cost. Taking into account the fact that fixed costs are in $, how can i add them in the "manufacturing_cost_flow" ?

Picture of the problem:
[problem](https://viewer.diagrams.net/?highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#RzfzHjuxKky0MPk0NGyAZlENqHdRyRhXUWvPpm57nfFW3%2BscFetJAbyR2RnqQThcm1jIz53992P4Sl2Sq9DEvuv9CoPz6rw%2F3XwgCQx%2Fy%2FQVa7n9aMPTfhnKp838v%2Bp8Gp36K%2F9z5b%2Bte58X6vy7cxrHb6ul%2FN2bjMBTZ9r%2FakmUZz%2F992W%2Fs%2FvdTp6Qs%2Fh8NTpZ0%2F8%2FWoM636p9WEiH%2Bp10q6rL6z5NhnPrnmz75z8X%2FzmStknw8%2F4%2BmD%2F9fH3YZx%2B2fT%2F3FFh1YvP%2Bsyz%2F3Cf%2BXb%2F97YEsxbP%2Ff3MAxpn0WmZbWu7deByFyLPb%2F%2BreXI%2Bn2fyf872C3%2Bz8r8I57Ah%2Fr%2Fm%2BpmKNYtvpdIC1Ji84c13qrx%2BH9Ph23bezfCzrwBZNkbbmM%2B5CzYzcuf119fn%2F%2F%2Fo8%2B6K4uwb3bOL2tyTr9s4W%2F%2BireUTN%2Fj6T%2F0wr9p%2BX9nCdb8l8f%2Bp8%2FEWEayv9C2NpnDPuEVLEc6fff1%2FEq3ivfT9H5%2FseFLB2BdoVBUvX9XdJ8x1u%2BjdIFTNVY5sFpd%2BT4212wJThGXf%2BFMOi7m4zbDsNhGvWxfBbDWTTd6SipHeavTYiDqPJ8NVa1%2F17Iy1fMVsmPphOIL3VzUJWoJYleYUau5QXGCQydhEYO8jGWVY8oiXxG6kfhfaQ1GjTxC%2FO3lx1Zto%2Fv%2Fz6%2BTnk5nMNgRPOGz4T0Gx5i%2B%2BTU8TbN76UpnPuN9s7FoWlGpmneZGlLvzixthi6pWkWNPN0ydEnC75%2BF8MiZYtmdd11%2BZL%2Fu%2Be9TKZv%2Ff%2Fo421qOB66ZOav8e2%2FpvXm73bwN3dWNC2f11d3aOuvz%2FfPkpNP5v8Xz3DjemxVI9h5CfMefw4%2BKH4V%2BqUvk%2BklyDwrUvv4%2FjpGpnNbVhc1ojqHnheHq5T4LLzxdI47VscPcyJqPswF1eSLymozJcPzsWdQVHjWlbXUvmE3mI7pjKq3gtjhKNp%2F3oXTFdk4KzbBc0FVu1U7oUCMrHHABWhZ%2F%2BRD38UnKN%2Fxq3K8kG7pMrSoOIOrKAqPxbz%2F9emtgMTId7RA%2FTjYiajX%2Bajg3mwUnPcXzhz1HjpIpvSYlT%2B%2Fd3%2Bvu%2Bpz4diH5ozJtOmzhh0Dcu3JcmdbsXPgL%2FGlbDv3Rj9jSd81iiUkPwK19V%2Bsn4mwRebh7WbAkDTr7qBAvS3Uq7MOhWwrVcEcmrvx7ifECmwRfdyrm%2FNLIzGHMw521RAxKzMJmw2y7V1lv4aEua%2Bl3N%2FfM3%2B23%2BXtWhu8rbc%2BiB%2BuHK1KQadOy7slj759hftiLSt7N%2F2UZBpKhcyyx6teVLbjDSWqB8Wpz4OF5J7V%2BLWy5y470NFnDe8HQQ0nl7uhYLWGe0pdTqpU1ZHe3pdDZD5OLm0meA6j1eg0Z%2B9%2B%2B%2BWNm50weDetjx%2BZx7OIx3gLjlW39kVVWyT7HSzivUOv70b3Pn3yTusI2XmVGGOSTG%2FCiqZuK4VvZzVTmOS9koaAPn9E2C9d7u4dp8tOLOxkdNlGkaZRqeTbqLLvDlbu5djpj4qfiJVYT%2Bq5iOCpdT3w00RwbbLiP9kCXb4%2FltZ5B1%2BKZUNDdC3WByMOuyZDsYC5kDc6mfdpMr792nZTHwp%2FjEQtKeX93olc%2BY1Ur6gIoUe46sKvwrf1lFEPqvdbr3nIDlgRuzZ%2Bppq9H5m8jQQmZDJNji%2B5%2Bw0b8%2BWTUK6wOBSb9x4m4NFywxtEXcYJPnEn6FJCl8FaicQyljy1VGJit6YV1LyVvVrgZThZ2eH2XJsuMdPkvPKO5OYUKR32dqjiJD0Po2jPsGbVDc6qTrTV3uGw%2Btj5NCawqD4ZX0ef2zkaz3tyKrwxTQTVCmvsNBwXyF%2B124ipRFW65u9%2BCZ7RJomVEXWB1KNV9d2FiJkbuNk8J1ffu%2BXyuhUBrEBgHZxCZ0Rku6m8XT5T1k1N14goCxZvxfZQ3rlE25UoWhGhaHbPh%2FASt%2B%2BdnTV%2BIq%2FSSo%2BO5j7fxBtvo2UmBu3V4SoRHbue4mmNfSU6a3YRdJ6OtrcfydqZjBFFmW6%2B%2FULLMkZ%2BCCWR4LRitdpbWUToqq%2FG6gLsqAeTW6%2BPCH35HkhYbT3zF9jpgZxaRujQwqzK1o30ar2zgcz4tS90Ud1aPcCLnGjokJnDvKtPhDg%2FPtDsofNMbW75XkDMpyv5dPVZ2eSNXx57rxX6PsylCQ7vvbcqgXgmd%2BTLzzoI8jtdH6O3%2BiBMFpvK73W269sWNyelM9Ac%2BTYnjSFNTYgNrJLK73ZptvYg1PDgB6%2BoBnn5%2BU4hHVRLeFKJgZrFXWm1M11qyO5AzTS0luPuJtfv2wE0wp3TTU4zhBG1F6sD28fVPnor%2B9AXC%2FBJPIPKoX0bo4nXnurm6ppJZ9Ucg753m8IrKk6FOTTQxcjeKkTjLZarqltkP2DTyYERvvE031G10L03aEEzcHV9dRKhliqH8FEsTNq6IUYvp646cVzAVq8pLZLECeC1vZo2SrFNpZhPoOHLApMQCjddpj%2BdW5vp4Mv8JLr8z40dSJkyClUhZAY%2BOvdXld9kgQRSGupKSd2%2BSbtxw9eDmu%2FeCzOZ3GvOU58sC0JWGMY8XBl4OfvdbGQjrE67dzf7VUOR6HAmIX0CY%2B15UYnKr1HnSGVKSJc%2BimRtGPS6iB9qWvdS8fM50MD117XpLlbO0ixjsbwlrrKlo4pj27Klfke5BKafa4Qhqh27FcpIPkH%2F7Oq3QMZWrfrhhY9OY8qg%2FOuPaa60X%2FXY%2FV6dugDHrj6BGYMfC4FnT91EI%2FUuafZd%2FJmVHU1Xn3Ib5v7shSoTMzXb2OGzTo1iidYsZRRSkn84YKZxpn11ZOPUVfT5vdL5p%2F41sHhMrpiIp64uyxe3xD%2Bs8rXyF%2B059oZUluz%2FATTaeSf36q9d%2B1BGo%2F%2BBFx498nWjYZSE0VdyYhRObEMT1nl%2BbDpAUBxN576VvmszsxwNw1JPDMcUIEVhFtoyix8xTG0Aot4ffLTkHOFGgR7pprnmNu4X6uRT%2BJOKHJ%2BQhQOMW3%2BzfvaFwjtbyoQZKArNYE%2FF9Wn5tfigLnh4KEvS5tFCT2Yaj80ym3%2FQ8TbeZzRTso%2BmEL5OmcNrANLD2af3PuZlgeXPOBY%2BZDb8%2FB0z2ee9TU651yl6UJ5FK7IBkxzrDUwNxwARz88ssB%2FmNIp%2Baj%2Fj913x5oNXAegUCn%2BGKWciU0YkDFSIf6KNRum6AVijGbBvpp7H64kE9ItCsTOC5uKckYUbTkJbQphYR1cMwQUn0EDgDIBjOWUoiLqtz4%2Bp9l6oK4zsV3q9iLAEep3onwi4HBJoPI4eCi1qGOzipcZWV0VwC6T%2BerhsOFLC9hVh0ddu4Ph3x%2BvcPZAOPykw%2BHUyw4hdgHaRHwCA1J5geH%2BNwCB6lBnCX5XoS6bHZoGYXF8LhxIXKFro9wc%2Fa14v5D2JR5Zuswg5yUwmqODFd9tV98TU4%2FGv%2FsEpu3vL99u%2FPWJL%2F3SU1aNzugp2cDXAOJJf7RfO6ZIus6AtGGSacHf7Mv47HjdKg%2BimbrB5l%2Flbat26FhYfnfZhIvTcdoLozSsZIvtCbM%2BdzyXJBnwlqoa8YaBzI50%2FLmyGWIfD5iHpaj%2Fm%2BennEDeKu9TmBkUSziWKMMdQwJUHeE6h3LnPUZGRGb59UgWi%2FkQxEw5g%2FKiRwHL7BT0uwUhyJ5Ws%2BH1Qp8E2d1ROov3VNr57jhl%2F8xBvPxIU6lQfHGGvDdPrMgV39%2FbeIqngQncogu3XqggRf%2Bcm321PRMa52zwN8R2659J%2FIjJVTPo%2B9iII5oAvXo7uhh8%2FQN0y2b38jarIfoP50X7MZ8lDZQ%2FWRiXmABIXvwbWKEkz0tmTHOwth%2B9fc0vaa5%2FfvWeO0EufGHsWgsYNI7bx%2FPUQB50WQMQgwh3ZyLM%2FH65LpaZhC9E0rZ%2By5LbKZxSpMEeyvDrCcGKAp46G%2FAob14%2FB4yQgOvv7cKZUrfEeeUPFLxx4E00NP0pgyHFybz8AAjbl16Un%2FnIr9LvBjC6PpVvfzKlIorEhLwB5e%2FLrnDHMrHlFgAFu8zvdvwlYEYQiMPOGqYIIjEnVR42uztYk3m86eZqgE7FTSbaA2ijT53Vcwm8zSqUqjP6bqNb7CJHcDoj67%2FW7pjz8boG5PKWXLj14XAcBOnpiGf%2FzhX7y9x0v%2BsNcCifcVT89zfzAf%2BluWO9UwfXVwcjo6QNJ35RXExSIR6nbBHO9db5kvJBBzI%2F0251lgsjOx9L9g%2FOKoxCGZbe0ec9OnpmixQwM0EgqTqi%2FXR%2Fh%2B7ANCgU2JSG34r%2FH%2FFlyAnBgLYjEL6AJyrCJgxRu04NJZrJKKxhKhOYuWRjSrzj4yWrDmZ1cQsoPMRyDoF5Rbv0QP%2BlvdSKWURn6XRyWOj78S4KZxcNZw%2Fhlr50RBLL8%2Fgb6uVsD%2F1vnYfmcnJRkPxYNgIEjIFjDt3NLy5SXCKla6y3sDAtgaYMDuO%2F0pA1%2BlV6QfBOypPtAfWCGdsqAcLoX5DwCHvlkJLG%2BNqQFDGhpH876%2FNBSFmB7P9FixD%2BEuYgb%2F46B%2BVnAL%2B9hkZu2zY9VHFy%2Fr5oOCBwjJs6zovskkBYszF7UKKBPoSnh%2B58OszpLX3wDQTqQhVVCCUDuA1bnbqOsZ8fxfx4OLM%2BRS3CThsSTtvO7O7%2Bw43M9sME2732yFTLpvYI0n4FhQrjEVc%2Bnz4HxEWMH%2B%2B0k8mcp0Qh7BJkUX1UKFqpTfzNUcsBbSV%2Bgzmox39QIBCVNjnbbSpIibTf%2FHt%2F9nLOzWlOAuYGbwj3tReZ02MGkrAJn0IUb%2BA6RIh7ADWOOSSVzDV1Bqc3b%2FvU%2Bn5KfQthIKAY6Cm%2FfyAzwG95xc%2Fu5ZnQ6no0GRqFbI%2BW3D7ObUpnN6npKdIIsOA27G40D9rGvFOznAGelpzYBWg4paQoZZgVuvsIeyQoDhn0rgIIbxwTg7LMZ%2Fg2J6Wemgb7zrJo7qg85RQ3gq5e6Or%2FdwL9bNK22%2FQKrypT64DqEhWGRFwvga0OhOy9xrIxze%2BNiY5KHUFD8BrzSQl%2FcK5VsfkMoOypZPUDgQz7Lo5WmGbt%2Be5P5PQlQ3mgK0oLOJPiLjJQDXbN6ZsZpogZ%2FNFHIXwushcBQ5JzKkSJjKZZNiwK%2F%2F7IUMiPTfCbxSwHBr3mMNF4UiHR89xdlgXi64niHUl5IS5crTnUyEoRYVPiCUr8DYWaJfnU3yytp79OmTfIR2E6BnjiBRlGBfrkvHUXOdmET%2FxkQyZyVFPtbbv78nq7rKx0ux7xH0xUjMm6Jze9lovDnCM5S5kuefhElU1Wq8es7TT1%2BqwnFLgZ8AK%2B2SbqGrjOL9kujXLtZ0GR0U%2BN5KCYFSGniFE7gX6Js2y%2Bs5XNgaznI1WDkk1ofnej217uM0shZJcOwY0Pr6vsfkDW4FJngol5xu4t%2FxsGevMVUjAZkUq6l%2FF78FDdzLUQ7PqAEWWaYnnmHERU4pUwShek07aYXIYcfXPqUVxR%2FITVe7AmEppQZikgzWL7kGrYt1X8S3g0emT2turJe9gdruZQ%2FItoiyFlAqUNHvPIXFWt5oBK7euo%2Fyby%2Buxo%2BwZZIeanPjMV77xBLH80kpahVGvE12GY2mI6kGYzdl8k42yy5dIFwB21BRu%2B0LJaNQGSl3NqjjR3VxE8IpfiukMujXRDTHjOGtl%2FYLY2T1ajGgazMtOXirL0jsWGJrmhdlv0PCR%2BpI0ePTQm4wche9O6oVD%2F9JkLA3W0BT5C%2Ful1BeI%2BhSYbnUwAKa9fhD3EAxrJ1lw4IFS1LpVw2Bgc7idWdw97J24dKpIf%2BZwdubqyj4ndtjX9E8aM4arAWzZEIb88vuO9xtZk4cinIlACGngfRJUaYyMOGqn9G6wW5YPlAUoG1gF9utvKv%2FAnPS%2BAsNKNZ9gXneUrSS24UGGOgie88OZhv8i7DP%2FJIaH1Hle8sHuoREpFH38E1FaEVfVfNPJS7eU0mgviO2R5LYoE74TVLUAJgbR0GggTGSlXYah0dI%2FKfaH65q3fT9NnXatrfuz2%2BH2eg9lC89NYrv5B7UYhtbWfqJtNeiV9VUcCKfF%2FPWC1%2BXEj0sXCQtCcG4DsNu0DZ2KR3jyxDXj%2FSDAksLGbW130ZHcfWEFVUidE7PoWXClwAvS2nWHYsq2ZGVpbvkQobGjiKPb2cfYopwyj5VSEjhv4CUfec53OaaTJcl0YwOU2K7w7wp06XbGWx732FyfHdaTBtObCAbf0J2srILH2yPcu%2F9BB%2Fb%2BBoEFWp6nVtXDxSbr0Y4XIFUbzfw%2FScEQzecxYybhK%2B%2Fmnx%2FDm55gNR6iSWwGj5A57rr2IoxJiv0vnpdcyWxa8FG2rdJbH2tcqia89O3aTQtrShR3I1mzuTK%2B7adWXgm0Ql3DSHSofEsuGf3apKp3vCMdBc2HhqyStW3fDN%2BDX8ogzZca919YeXu5egvdsmwDIzLkbOQT4MtwQC%2FR2xde%2BaTsy3zWnYMWI4Wr6b3pMLLMQ%2BK7y78x3n%2BygIdNHRVo1F2fNuy2k%2BoofyeDAZHjVC42Oq%2BrKXE0ACKtp1u34V7evnttZ3LP2cOJQp0p9CPwDDSCfKysaPZF5YL8ConFzAzs7Keaa7a1GRXbUb641dsW7t7OBaF7vK1Pfw3%2FxuxNonSTTRqWBYEW9RNrKdi9Rm%2F3uXgX6XAJm2UOjpj1xTF3ZSY5jOIrtkDsnbv10eovgK5One28%2FrLDm0u%2Fofijndi4VhUchD1M%2FqXZ0ko4tr05AjyA877bsujb7j0xc2aip65kO5Cs%2FPmUH%2FGR9qwmsreaQFQndLP%2BjrM6Ip%2FP1835E8oirmMORUuCs9kaPVM7e3HhGnkJhnx9MIZWXfsDpVDpwTOtk01ssfbj%2FfiLqLZ0KFAGNB4TkFcdyP91oIxoYHefuuVK4pbTsfghLj%2B6G93MteTT%2FdgCJS7jSPuDyDwKnDOa%2BDFnUETqEgFLTqQqIAIMGheX5TqpPQ9KvaNUIQY4Zl6voygw%2BLSZq68TfORV%2FqJ0UUPl6cr4rlj1nUn8QSS4HYlq%2FID9szLZs2iX3zlLxLQYqk3qEbFAvlLOYH%2BSLu00mH%2Fxm6utGIUl8LXokr944VJ40hX%2Fn0pKN4tlsEDqfPDvHJ%2FuITzHV7VGEFPv7reOFYMIdpzuHTvsv2buBpkeFrEPqyhmGn6mfJqc0kSRczWoTaeHewsrB5869lzcsx2Op4ep3vqOIulsXl6vq8GVtYGEfpSNVjlTsLZiCV%2BBux5SjaZswVjp4Pz9qmP0dsBD2M2ZvEfsKxOAKCyBdr4%2FjWE9r%2BHBs2kgV5Uiv8dviw6uqcGwInx1874s8nqTLe1DMRx1%2FSsmMaFKqYB8%2By8T0PLkhyF423dswyAsT3e9cOk15A5fPWVNEhFE%2BQrYWpxUbsbhbqnsKuv51j2a7Uy3GAekSfCiG3lr0eYf1rD%2BeZEjXKJlJBdjhyQGbd9kIMHwzF4cbkFUtdtVqJSEVejmPyRK89eOoNmjQPrfDLDMen%2F9Va4NeOfahtKUSCfBgHpZ1dM8rUjTuOsn%2FGjia3Tdq3%2Buz04OoXNTbf4e4iwp6qFbOl%2FKKxlxlX7Bl3IF5J9017RiKDD5aevpzWZcu0ipkGDgY2LWvJe73bejZT2l%2FFAVx%2BSoTJdCyaXCP%2BAN1O9NXqCE5Iq2KFVMlaPnpZizLZDXUk%2FetjHDuORQUatOTR89pzl%2B8tyeXtaoKs%2FeGvFLbRnSKsdrLT3Qtend91SGkM7StN%2FcCj6wX1y88ZD40%2B4X2BD4feuPvm1xqzvW14WIURvzLhelgHQZ8nWPgXaHFMsZy3aqG2KB7e8jwLHE0wGwFw6o2z9lQDR%2FJRpAbKYrPIXhmiU20bVq%2F1tPEeZm19GFTN2kwTSkEaTnGUEehdktLT785YCnVojsQuxZ7k0%2FAQDUcsZs5YaW9rzFcKiCvXZnikY5u9ok2Vc%2BBd0eytJEuR22vRNH6H1vSqwwprlriwMTYFMmy7qgu1vd8ge%2BDPLFfe1qrwXsSVIqyvrsxHju1NCeOwn%2BOzkInWix68DSqgwzMOO1q7Xg3TLbdX8qNyodDpHQ4a58j4nexIZLFJ%2B2pKfN%2FdYpGe5ShccFWsORuau0%2FY4qbwLSnwWn35jJm79U4UXRTbjFj90XZf9nta593UaBBqlctEo7d%2FOqHlASmQpLqKJOm%2BLsp2%2FI2gA4QNOtxfKESjX8dQpUmUPub90sHolJN264J8WVF%2FjNbhXmzhx2YsCAB1WbKfiq%2FHVtX8k6ASiK9h2kocEXP72nWvwbInqvlQPXvkSiAXbrGERHABJMeqnnfq2hJhL%2Bq%2FMSx%2F6Z0VXNG1QL4aQHmGzDBOczr2eBnyV1tADGm%2FBefG42k6QTRETD4eNavJWb48Fo3kCQAXvBG36VaqREXTdFSQ%2FEFJFjUO85MeiLFCH%2F98dd4y2%2FIdRKjr88fKWQeuYwF4hikC3jzM6KMoWPXrAIzkYOPgVTbafOe9jl%2B5GBA7XIh5YiFhr7H9byiyVQkaWmwX1462yK8cC%2F3imDOe6KW8dFAmjRvVgkbGc%2BsLuNJXbAS8tlfuTaaNH5zPACCWshffc%2Fty79UXjC9NE5Y3gk5crxik8cdeFjU4YDvtBz9OsD86dzrMmnOBOSBrcrzamityre7RSF2dPtnTrSNnz%2BapHq3M6B4fzLFtjDJEVvmWNSTfiObec%2BlHUUmknThgReLWXR6JgqoIG%2FTJD6t2mDKg5TuVadyI4qbX6lP%2FJx%2FJnauQwW%2Fbxfhxn8y9oxvPxS66Z6AtGl3l7myKKOqX1K1UwSb%2Bi3xVsV2lWoKwTb743mB4F3rHCY%2BGf6eD6aR%2Bk5ZTZt6U9lkABOF5JD6oWi%2FgUgp%2F38AUCxj6eTFvYepNbKhwqVY5ueSOOzAfpVzbcdjwG9pflcV4fPqEGDm605h0EDUgLCLvnhz6KfR1qVlxEhCHSN2gvVgMOnfh03fCr3u5mEryclRiE%2BE0sbdHFS9%2F7wkVIPn0oijV6bYCRKKIbqerX7wB9OFQ7plpIz2YNTr8NkVLYtszZMvLUmt8AhlErZe%2FwdJ39PS9DaKHbAx%2BMq%2BNl%2B3bGR5bvHItZ5weZHyPWQJRed%2FgNSPTIGZMbz7Aoeu4ZJaburF%2B8MQgyoQlOIr9ds0rrFCBQmacDFaNb02bW5fJY4cCE2wVUuW79an660PIyonucmWyYrMlJItwqFW1LYhgjCDnlvWJaxZ%2FAX88OCB9hoPL9vbmwiNhh23sm5MT8iW0moI%2BX09V8DZnlW4PYR0rPr29yNopbQ4UrOEm6yfChayOU9B2hb%2FcyZ22anRv9S7qd7OF9%2FB0JV%2FJ8q3FJISB4vfytF%2FdkyQ6NXXmPgZVim0oGerJp4OdEvUMcYL1luV%2FpWLsSgtmTQXJnfHtyaLua8edZV7UMqBSB11mEr%2F1l12FsGiRWPUMp%2BQ1Z3ej9I%2BKv0z6DMvNm1ZADkK5IyU8ZzQ8POvm2JfeYQ8TS3litBsxMd41oiZe18VE%2FSwodkPWEX85Wm03owBPG2GRd10rFJrVfnxk3QLKjfezkpltNplBUrWovsIfSc%2FFLSatsmcb7Fe6DI8KSDpM8zPNvwStbbYNxoub0G76Zsd0lEFJ2eydTdPxPK6TLXQfVkTFJOIsvLZKUPvk5zrPEIPYYVHESbmsF4iICeMLcxAK%2BR0x3SpzzrzOvA8%2FEvMM33ma0jgSxerWUiFgW6JzXywmfL1fN2%2Bz6kKySw5RVLVK30fec2H5dCJxHnkgk9RkbqDaK%2B7rHUqhSXcVD6dsI0iJ5Kz8zvFqJRC%2F9WvlBEHPb2uKfBvbW70vUyVqq1MMcLbEtnDLy%2BuB1U%2BXzNizP7xrx37jJktnCOhOT1g1Q7DxZMM8h2PWSk2HFOy8prIxgsgqyBYbPPJZ6Cf7nhjGWIQRkRjVfeLbCKK1TP4ikv0%2BkznDpLD4s%2B1pdgYmjR9eTidRNJp8Hj0vkOtCKeQkKavTndRAHOTpiIR5q%2B0YgC7Up7GLGqACJN4Y1x1w34einqXX9bg39RoinGkrjqFHFpV1WZLndIPnnP05s7JFv5qTveWqeLZ40YshyC4zSRLccB1gJEfwqApPuuEeNWBCFmX9IJPxSIJ3Vd9xD9sAbqHHvJMQ5pczlyifgnBV8GIqiRNdx18aGIQ7NtqFBzH6xCDmwBy%2FfqHCvmnko5TXG9DDzGYmU7yylNuY8ecggAGtNgcL25J5RQJ78jVU9JrxfAIyf%2FUOQYf6CDO8kQjC685BcBKfvWTeommtsmiW54EHY9gF8X4wDruTJHSpHqKNsY4FZX9ZVmU5J9N5PDP53jQ3zPBh4s%2BKLUFOkg7YoEWKkMYAY%2FnZPUJW8ndcSwyE1Y9s2lUJG2Cx%2BPU4SSdxgow2TMvsKH8V6wyPJb1Jtz1l96K2eGMP3eSqu1S8%2FTd57cdVk5giz0qpvBX1wvIEszKg6PPRbgVxEB5UuJUHXUINx0a8GiUbJdojlC1j%2FXN97%2BZbVBBLQwcpellhNNNnRhEkXxjsL6ULEzg8dYOKb3kA9g7AgOX33eUDIXLqJ5HCXxEEbc9sV61qYO2B3v9lIbll%2BNAH%2F%2B1WP%2BWRkyo4P%2Bu5j8Dor5%2BMatLU0xTHVDoVUzK2SSmcGjuiXrJrpvHGkVW0%2F6mb4VJf%2FCptcZO8LYTMclnwGLjlgkknhXm3B5Jh%2BQQxt2PUclPsULRVyhmR0T8LIeSbLvNn8fsSywnKlMpciy4holZZ7ZupEfrPbD5aWxw7RSJDQVzYsei0vfwgIsaw7%2BGBMN%2Bo4eZrAYX5%2Fu0%2FPUNKWugV3sYMCnG9d2kTLWkbRptiqiF70bFiDb1ENMkmrzi02E%2Ft6kHzDgaumUT4b6MdZPwLifomI02SaAVp1A90GSD22LBtQiRJ3DAVwRGk%2BPsbQH6HXbZyke%2B6NImkW53wZ2qkiBG2GKnsmoXTv3%2FQKWD0uJnJ%2Fb3pSlfONsmmLFx8pSjLg09mFxtCsFRcECnifZaVATWSQhEeVEVPl5vcugQCETn9MjTs3d9rjD42dSbaYEpnYEA4xQ7HfJYNI3ycXPc8xmRRoTMPc8ZWPQCxGRVkWhBDLggDq6NSAXEeeYAgMbiANswBHubOQ8Ts7U4bNVMTcZyCdRWsQMuMv0a3uXKg%2BCqd07QS949GroG7rFkGd%2BkG0BIbALOS6XcoRA5zOqM9011F6tyw4z6u8Wd9YMB6ruLmdzB0eX7bwBlqWOHy9HF1G%2B%2BGB8Chlczna3rUrw8XgIvJ7JyTCv4w%2FscyygQNSNLrsq8pgWxsEUTjibFMDxJ4OEVeqOWXeQqnf7v6%2FliT%2B08wYkW1gswxByGOI%2BqugEetAXFYZ2YD6SRYwI2OXh3VFCARWb%2FgLHy4NIv8ELOjZNRp6jX4Lpna2YOkSR6kwNPUAlVQFj5pF6yZFZFPnqgLTuHdz9fN%2B4%2Fh19BaPDdGfaQiNxKh%2BUtEn4SrrJr9gWPLroxKNYjwMtmIa97vl%2BbbktxPdU%2F9GS5BIAZ6VU551w7z%2BF1uAD2JHuKE63YNqG6wF3P9aQPOnQA1zXJHJs%2FlZGaRF1Hon49qOuslrij3g35tdVD2B4ktv7IlAlVfKmpXVUYTO5Bw%2Bq8Qjuw3LiXcOFPpqhD4qSGIL4XeXYhi5IMmv6LljYOIQUIqmL66CmfatUM2GQBTNTtrZj1wB%2BSJ0jLnC%2BYDKgJgOkUuDKcP9awbxtBkaS7jKLniDcatyqfchILxmu%2FZ6PYy%2FSOkkShFXiF8DPWTbuMP9W34L0H7xL%2FfRnzwFyeDaCwyQ7WHXjwjHb9hQ34%2FmoVomjEmx7MZXzjbpdFjwyjWxeDCwwSZ7yXfsQ%2BW%2BS%2BTv6yX%2BS%2Fsq7OWEYNc3GbjVKelGnIK%2FnenA9GTG5BcfMqwVt7tIbqL1l9IYoHQ2%2F7jEdII079YpdHVLpQVYcOMH%2FdLxebUbN2DysTrFLKfE7qfl38JZ9EXURn%2BVhz5hUBnmKEmF1Y3zLDfDX04B04jGoztz7RG6%2BOW0j3YPyydBPO5v%2Fx%2BQTe%2BKLyZjDHiJ%2BH7kTX7S9CcF6KA5S%2BJ50AUHyIKZ6a2Iaaq3EK%2FtswX8vU8Rv3%2FmRcHLmL7bMtxnwsr8oP59fPic%2FaNsFKlL6sktNgJLyeKBOQDbWD4r8JyuZxHNhGoZtnABLlT3fcPqA%2BEvEbVDyb2n3SdXFgy5wxk04Xcxanmyl86SnpLXoVfX17pT2SOHkLCaTXhwlUCCJlReoFv8w2D3RGEbnr8K9tIpaRg%2FsXsBuPse7Z95%2BcZQChBByQV1FBymw7yHP0Kj%2Fv40Qd3DoJ%2FspHMQOJ4Ym8ksBS%2BiZ9xvQivtr%2BYfpcO%2FFH3Ag5595CaSjROtABmYmt%2B8ARm9YmrBLEu7Nq9uSvCF5JHH4JJO9RMTFVskFcqA108ikEfjvS6tvvdSdVQxIRTpzEo9JelYEnq%2B2P3cm7jUXLxSayXRBK3Y%2FDpX8TiPg54IkFmSKRl%2BQGg7jQRqw19keAqvFl%2BQGLXBHIXjGIXHMuFz7jilEcDexzpEAjFv6M0b55F3Dsu78LgxF%2BldwUoNKhxahfFQbtXOXpezqRc2I8tdKfG66CVZKFNNlBQcsPthpjZ0RE8dNKYV7EL%2Bh2cEvqc%2BqdzhP9r%2Fp7G8Cp4Kdpf7UCQgLHSBFeu2W%2BCDIkTQln%2FRYsWahgiEsj5W9ZX%2F6sm0e%2BmXZVX0FjhrEl1UTKWIJdPzXSxV7TnEUOkGacNf9xfQvQoEUGCSiGMB0EK4edHBfSLv1R4B2%2BXxf6Stv7TfyLbjKwbROtpYHByVTjNOEjFBoPYxJsCHaQygYkcg2DB%2Bvlvt3QPxcuCjKFT5Bts68a%2BeWXI5ZeXglyJuW8ARQm9FBBRW%2FfHsHXmUA2F%2BBph4G4Sa0kOsyhv%2F5jD4K%2BAImUnZR%2FjE848OOAIXhf9g9F8gN7rGJDMHF1X9TzYysPmtlZG62XXnHcycZ%2FqgqxC36FMNa3eQI5g1Zc%2BBCXdwjYXJOX92slBH7VcCX6pZ9AOv5BKIUj7RV%2FrPH%2B3%2B05CFJ1QfgFlGIIAcCdRVsQc8ArADwGZkb%2FlRkaonmqt0SR%2FZeZRlWkA1q5dvbfHP8osApoVy1j%2B3fmZDOL0dwrDVLq7wgO0PJjmdfJlAWb1a41hDIUP6YKyTby2KsdSh4NQIcS4aFlQWZP7vrYPn4wxDm78Ob419XB8oPEszSflFMUO14sFt5rKJyg%2FBsWfSKpKcuXD5o8T0M3D2gPUSjNAyc%2F%2BV8mpzUiBNLqZpbIYL5Zy5LL8Yj5x0TOf9sK5yMx85uTi8uAIGbpeTZoBWlsnfi0c%2F0vK7be3BLply9oWRlHkz6k9DULE6gQy%2FsIyADChzTCmfMdnsRAAty2wERCgqsFlmc5HnZEZ2mKEURV5XlAMsbaCZewla0Tkfw6S0BxL0oyzxCY9zyV81uUPnGoxL5p%2BuRmDlo1aCt5FH6wlWCVdpiM4hzGq1IPcR12BQCTaM4Hs5919voCKtjjapkUemoV%2FIM0hznmhIgAa9hrNjD2bjPzfiZWXTtFRWLN3SvEuw%2F1Zgxfns9dfbWrpgsy0OkZ%2FFYE9omGwTcA%2Fk3KleJfmkab5l6CDpGteTOWv9LDrPgpkE37TNdmc%2FXbScnR4voMxiRr3x%2BQ4X8JEWukdZmNIH6L1d1qGoSVQK5FbEaEiFHEeWtlRSlN6f9WwvBiBCgKY4GDEJD%2Bq2Ziri0uBx1nvD%2BiAHcWSt%2BwtsIrsoIm6MIKQLcU%2FHqjQI9NatCh5I%2FMDAcrMbmk397iMEVrvXQLOevkCKz4U%2B9iZ0JYW%2B3lItjbYv0oSA5zhue5XOUA50wtCN334ebbPWAIYdwQqSX5NJPxO%2FnsRKnkJr8B4oDKjBBl5EFywQI5eHc3DIDjlYWwOnAQaBZ6W3coiitPPpICxo79TQRanN7QuRxGQw5u6T%2FSWkc8zopYjWhJggySo1OBTy%2FZOB6De6LiObLVHulpLGQypAPsBKj3r5Z%2F8ud1uRfEaNsWhF7DnFkuTIOVdbV1IyEstnFNNW8o7qIpnXv5%2BNQzed7BdmMeqywwngPIHXv2%2B3zfiF5HU1OVoGo6B8LIcxMryOe8wcKPIqT7jPPLc2jOgYsK05LJhZ6IVcwF1YduPVBHj%2F9ZcABVB6jLbMeReD1v%2BVWDQMv9XBEB%2BGxAv4D87QIgFgp481XzKSgQStSIS2JMIo3oQu%2FGnIKPEBu9t7q%2BamrN%2BYIW4B1KTU%2BNuumL%2F5BAxwV3W9eP245WqSf67lgLXyukYdWVonSwPvbAQlJrTNifyAvTFEVkuJToBNej3KxHn3FhwSu%2FqyHLeP9caoA6lcnAp9198qZws2KUMHJXSX%2FcG7AGOkkvMAujxPCCt4DmRxP0zX2GULY5Vv6BqUdBPIbiq6J%2FTZgp98hb94pte0Rj4dHld4%2F897Sb%2BFeucotWlBUWCIiqmQ4zI%2F7dPSQZrmBkD%2FrkpqvKT%2FVMoNzMW%2F5xB2wQBSB505KdN9HTZfv92Xno1qOp1GX0dONeyJ3v%2BadYJpNiQI%2FYffsqwx2dnGOvfI2zG%2BT6KWwu5OsLhQSFXkrziXYF%2Fz8CxvP4XCXom%2F4fy6hX9exs9gsqnMZBuDA5fAcz%2B2f1X1z15fO8yOUxOCYESAS%2B7qMkmaOU%2FZ%2Bx4MM7R4%2FkzzLxQiVCG%2FF93VgIpkKsXhhTn%2BzD1HT7PXYdJz0wbBpCgeonMgHmPNx76WAdxjDbytTeE1k6wTqYd95mtZToSZ%2FLalxdcKPNX1hmGw7r9fo79do65WNeW1duT%2FFGpTSnN1lRsWUv2Mh5XXgl94Bb8LjEtK3ldLzGKTN%2BdiOyV0QPZNXtVhHmcLIckBaYARJtv%2Br7P%2BB3aL3j5QLdobvn3pwehu%2B%2FFz%2FkCJ409%2BexWMzKwmK1d0ZeRuQQLpYRsZTH8spgAmA9lle7isK6K9%2B03JsOqQExJqncD0%2Fv2lNpO1WHJcz7rZ%2BBoFf6KiSLryupj27KR9AJ139Yx9OWMTQjAzdAElZWTXpjjsJH7CBwEQ10qtZrjtxgmAQCpz7ydx2hin%2Bv7m35%2FHkfYf6qdaHDcQsByi4XQsQhknDt3AVuYDz7MLQiYOt7sBWBGBbgxqg4T8wZOoe%2FK1LcaO3SFl1Oz%2FAI7sPOlfU35b0i0JW3CUSB%2BP9c%2F8IZiCxnEslO4OUDgYAQx0Z%2FRmYzfnpFv1Y0n7%2FZP8Jpjgc1eC5vm7EMeFbHf9nTynMaZXzN1a3bcY04Dxrjkd%2FIw5xGSy%2FfWynawx8QfnKV3P0EnV6Vs%2FffY24UW6I1gbJ03yJZxZAx%2F4W2fhdpuirxdC0iu9zBK%2B9b%2BHjVbU0iStPWHPXU5XK9fsuSdkC9hPHxN0XOmeeM3tvcnFwP0iSlRAdkbbTu2sW11Qozt4rfdHY%2B23ffWcyI6fkr0d8otS6c%2B5YsvDlEYs2mmGQ3D8EtJH3X7aouzHes4R13q6nnkuwYliEyJxfIdesm7lP7p4x7E4q7VJnFrTcSQ5ReTZHt3FZ68YekMEOGXnB8Q0KsXNQ%2B8icjbAfbYJBaM10EVxqiZnnHrco4hygaL3ZNhfWCzStVYknEjX%2FrONGnPIC6TEX%2B3tA713r1c5X%2BEhdu%2B%2FdOHefUSrkXZVfvu%2F%2FkihQ88%2Bw3Dzkxto9NZFPahedlVedVty8q5wb5cAPPwYa5YXqWQqUL0gXn0sZXXdnTRGPBQGZPkPK%2FbqfEwWc6i2pGtJpkrjhXVERxrOgJ3nDWGF0bMsNqGUeubMqFCeHg3sUeveogDauU5uH%2F71Dy7ffqGIDG%2B%2BeD7K1eu1QVRFU8YpytOVeX3HlggpFSXZfNS%2BHL9C5rXR9Rc%2F5zG%2BeOie0QMC2CnzQEfze41ziJemEmTOvetKqXKNIu0zi%2BvRI%2FLf%2FeM5Ns5ynj0GNk70Ta%2BhcbecSPFIWy4dFlXxqffJqmDOGRDISth%2FLV69m6rx%2F6LU9tql%2F0T%2FmWqUQgVFdobRWG7Kf%2Bq9NeJvbBHn1BQ9lLJKKEaWESTPqY35VndU3BYRODsxyS630fDTRsUp2GLbK1P0zSctJSllau0aYsijWmlHTyKwlT8mS6Ouyq1BCs2j4FkdxCzms6hi%2FTNQgP3VvmERVldvw7hYTevt7ltRGVjPpCh%2BZEw0esndoj%2BXoSn9JiEnn7%2F5LGVq4%2Bwc%2FacOxs7V1eqzWgL%2Fyia1ymfLRSZCuGaVyeJHyCxGjNopoYNHwngZBFkhfH8xXln8cU%2By4V9hZKt6R8rq5r%2FdwaW%2BHgdtLnQXte0syYa6GS5rFGzVStW1J8jbJ8ScryO1enZ%2FgS%2FrRCSpfV4SaaqcuchTdPbHpHjFxfVwvYiiFaPQIpTIFUdSagXd70my1kXUFCfgXYKxCAFwpg%2Bz%2FJQTiVJIkxgYgfhaN2nhU5mvgNoIz863ay13sCGcAobnH823LHI2676XxtB4pS1%2FKMHaJMVMv3p56vfFZFDHsGuBmyYV0TNJpZh5EqRM3TXZkLr1sRrg0JgwwKURs5UqqZySQUUCHPt84n8VVE8bQQiWdYdO5uZ%2B3YYjGZ%2B%2FJbcaoziQ1XYLWXUP7xZ%2BP1U5iV%2B76dh6gKZ7DBZANGD%2Bau%2FFHx6omsn28zv4wL7acDQwQXaHPMYEVbsmZSqIJhZifycJwM5BAatWc4HVGjgWWfpa7s7agbTpHqizwCFvSVHlPY9cFca4MkAqY%2BYDDQNsMAV%2B7GZUsZZzBDwNjxMPA37hpc3nmaKt9Ql1HFSfGx%2B%2Bcybmx933%2B%2FiGuo2q8n2M4QJpDCIKOuDtdiKX3VB25S3TLpMeTfvsorGlOkvcAEb4yuv1GdpO4xM3srnszA5sbFjNKAMsm%2BZsEYwhMT%2BEJErtfusZxgYvN5AFAc4tAoZOEUTVXEKWR00UgB456PMu%2FnqXMSqhqIu7j%2BH%2FCzypB63yI9ZRO%2F46AiCeXEXK%2F42GEUiVI9%2BDziTwMQ4%2FvM%2FyRcBIu%2BEC%2FDShGRS%2F9pbHezT2O39B%2FEI8HkxAG%2Bu0s%2Fz0SQvD9ZNpRS6aKWyGcgXD%2FWUOYIx2lubkioL6ZHoQB7oVfMGaHutS269KBdwFu71%2BoWeduVTi9akJWwfGnt8aj8Bc1HbVjiBUU%2FMWf32F2w%2Bl6bjq9YDYKbxpSgGHtBkzkGT5dIFdvIkCF401fRVqXzbIjg0UgCoUfufiTjRM9y5%2BeKSMP3A%2BVT8wQuMvJ%2FOoX5oD7xjces6Hi6z3p6f5mMzZCgagteGXQqv0I201yXxRSgN6VOysI5n8U9J7uAOKn1KaqtEpVW9hBM7fWge2NUQq5ZpWcO8Z6C%2BDfCNBC4f%2Fqp%2BqsKAwWr2%2Fxy5mU1mCuBEx3ZPhRojV%2BTWa2X5U9YcQaqUFrY3Wnfq5KueClfAF8yyet9Qy07iPr7S5fWqKGh78JoKS7POJRPRXJ8Rh%2B3RxXJnQ5ZAeNZoP2byGMuHWXZ%2BqxBmgeGsoq8Gdo2%2B9f1ROPv4DLD%2BV%2BKqAsuIVXEXN0FftE85mifzNYC%2FFO06cPzOdSWJoSWnm4yNz%2Fk%2BlMLrq7ODiUv7mu%2FK7boNlTA8NnqHm%2BiJqWm51Z8TfmPd120Km6XKvQwgf9dSQ4jM6aMjW8c%2FWuC%2FArJWkKdQ7XcSC8xBnWratBvyVIl9PS7DiY82PMk34li8WjIQtR8oj9J8ivFQIrlpKECnBMTZurFnnUCLXp%2BvVL8P2fQMJlo9H%2B0%2FHKO9GWpE%2B%2F5WXD2AhKIf1nhwNvqcrPS4G0F0jDDij7Yhfhs%2FjFTWZuzfsnKMDoUV0sXuV88OlV9D%2BLnlr%2FCjRpXE8LYxOpgb0k5YF53FB4%2BMa1gFqzCrvxrwFDH1m4M4ykI0Y1wSsu8pR46TpAHrae507w%2FeRnNiwKnAD7W%2BwcKgQdT2DfKcy4ZYaMQRz4Xt8jvzx36tQUVTCL4MrC8dfwS8hansCXeVKpg%2Fy1Zk6Mti2EL6cMHjInW%2FjXC8E6YKHSl1fXPyxissoQB9F8OEsQzdRk2BRDJboQw5NYjbxIhjqE1pdav6m156y3Io2zq8ToyLHqYvDB6LZxM1iqqlEFALYRpBxlrEIo6aVwEZBBKUoSl2zp98iCyIZA97hpQQcBgWiSP4VHfjNV%2FEXC0mTMGQc3Uf39ArHcDzHFJP1yhiv9SW9%2Bkqy2p9u2tfc%2BAuZQn0fSR6MxaHOAHRQ2IBJxzXjzcuBlxoiC9ITUWAcwxs6QU00HrDvFDi81UwLN%2Bc6kQzDrkiWShRXu79KlOyDPgkdPq4A%2BF%2F3G5ijon6UJkz7kUIwX9RTwDbsM%2BKQGCExS%2Fq%2BiftzICJyvpD66haafeLGrAGfqrrMWV5H5vr78UbFYmdE3sufv8ZejzRp9fofVio5ybiWdqQVZVoPey4t0CO0WJpiDUZ9DjaME2IRnRFDZLsBqWDryby%2FNFnpQyYekuXEaD6tBbINi39cX%2BG8UB8xyqg%2BAZxJhCDYUpwLoJ%2BvTH%2FTxyn5MHZBbtjCGb4z8tnVBGcvogYiH2dxx%2BTtjwPnIbxhlHI%2FokciDSIRrBCLVnM%2BU88SviLJPJbkJXC9f8%2FY3r3xySXl1T1enehggVeevTKoofxS6uUZQlexgR%2BmH9f%2FlS8OnP9X98qBf%2F3u6r6SyzGvtiWl8FD%2F7mB%2BPf1Vvd%2FXoD179%2Fn%2F7wt6wNOqoG26v94UxYCY%2F%2B%2BpevfN3SV%2F933%2F7zECjiMf95j9Z8%2F%2F%2Bd9WX%2Ff%2FR9vHfvw%2F28%3D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed costs are not in $, they are in $/time... what would be in $ units would be initial investment or something like that..

Initial investment would go directly as an initial value of your stock.

Fixed costs are for example rent... and rent is $/month, another example of fixed costs is insurance... and you pay insurance every month too.. which means it's also $/month

The are called fixed, because the are the same amount every month, while manufacturing costs are not the same every month and depend on what you produced

You should make your fixed costs as $/time units and you are totally fine... unless you have initial investments, in which case you don't need that parameter at all

Comment: Thank you so much, i get it now!
If i have an investment, should i put it in "initial value" of stock "manufacturing cost" ?

Comment: yes... if you consider the investment to be a manufacturing cost